# Basic regex match up to first period

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a search term up to a first period using grep

So for example, grep-ing through

```
foobar searchterm. hello world.
```

should print `foobar search term blah.` I save the above to a plain text file called `search`. But when I try

```
grep -i 'searchterm.*\.'search
```

it prints out

```
foobar searchterm blah. hello world.
```

instead of stopping after blah. What am I getting wrong here? The period star `.*` should match anything up to the first occurrence of a literal period `\.` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `grep` returns entire **lines** which contain the pattern, not just the matched pattern.

You can use the `-o` option to display only the matching text.

And you should use a non-greedy search so you only match to the first period after search term. You'll need to Perl syntax (`-P`) for that with the `?` modifier after the `.*`.

Try something like this:

```
grep -P 'searchterm.*?\.' -o search
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp matches the whole line, and grep by default output matched lines.

You need to tell grep to output only matched parted instead of whole line:

```
$ grep -iEo '.*searchterm.*?\.'
```

The `-E` flag tells grep to use extended regexp, which allows you to use the `.*?` non-greedy matching, so it stops at the the first period.

Hope it helps.